# How do I tell IntelliJ about TinyMCE dynamic properties?

Tags: intellij-idea, tinymce

I'm using IntelliJ to do some Javascript development. We're using TinyMCE on our site and it has some dynamically generated methods (its Events).

IntelliJ is complaining that it can't resolve the variable... not surprisingly, since the Events are generated dynamically.

I know that I can suppress the inspection of that line, but is there a better way? Ideally, I'd like to be able to tell IntelliJ about these variables... perhaps via JSDoc? Or is there another way?

**EDIT**

Essentially, this is for properties that are created at runtime and are not determinable by IntelliJ statically.

A basic example would be this code:

```
var Foo = {
  addMethod: function() {
    this.newMethod = function() {
      console.log("This method is dynamically generated");
    }
  }
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo.addMethod();
foo.newMethod();
```

IntelliJ can infer that `addMethod` is a method, but it cannot infer that `newMethod` is a valid method.

Is there something I can do to teach IntelliJ that `newMethod` is legitimate?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant,
but I found out you can add 'namespace' doc comments to tell IntelliJ/Webstorm about methods it doesn't know.

For your example, adding

```
  /** @namespace bar.newMethod */
```

makes sure that IntelliJ no longer marks your usage as invalid

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that IntelliJ doesn't infer the type of inline properties, even when they are functions.  The only way to get IntelliJ to play nice is to use prototypes instead of inline object notation.  i.e.:

```
function Bar() { }
Bar.prototype.addMethod = function() { };
Bar.prototype.newMethod = function() { };

var bar = new Bar();
bar.addMethod();
bar.newMethod();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't get to control how TinyMCE defines its methods :o(

Comment: Can you add the framework to the inspections? (SETTINGS -> JAVASCRIPT -> LIBRARIES -> CONFIGURE)  FYI--you can also add JS libraries to the project libraries in the newer versions of IntelliJ.